# How to go through a csv file and create map of 2 tuple out of it?

Tags: java, scala, csv, opencsv

I have a simple csv file that looks like this

```
Country    city        min    max
Germany    Berlin      13     6
Germany    Munich      19     6
Germany    Hamburg     19     18
Spain      Madrid      10     9
Spain      Barcelona   10     9
```

I want to read this file and create a Map that it's key is a tuple and value is a tuple:

`myMap = Map((country,city) , (min,max))`

so then I can go through this map and check if I have key `(Germany,Berlin)` I can pull its min & max....

How can I do this with csv reader? I am using `tototoshi`

I am using scala but java solution also will be great.

Comment: I haven't tried something yet cause I dont know what to try @Yazan

Comment: i am not sure if this site meant for someone to write a full code for someone else, it's about asking questions about specific point, that you have encountered while (coding) your own code, anyway, good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use scala split to get the values an a regular expression that matches the separation in this case whitespaces, then you have a vector, which the components are the words in the line. So the only thing that you must do is go through the array for printing or for adding elements to your struture in this case a `Map[Tuple2[String,String],Tuple2[String,String]]` structure. you can use syntactic sugar for using this tuples but with this code is easy to see what you are doing

The source code:

```
object TestCSV extends App {
    val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile("/Users/toni/learn/scala/test-stackoverflow/src/main/scala/com/cuaqea/csv/file.csv")
    val cache = collection.mutable.Map[Tuple2[String,String], Tuple2[String,String]]()
  for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines) {
        val cols = line.split("\\s+").map(_.trim)

      println(s"${cols(0)}|${cols(1)}|${cols(2)}|${cols(3)}")
      cache += (new Tuple2(cols(0),cols(1)) -> new Tuple2(cols(2), cols(3)))

  }
  println(cache.toString)
    bufferedSource.close
}
```

The result:

```
[info] Running TestCSV
Country|city|min|max
Germany|Berlin|13|6
Germany|Munich|19|6
Germany|Hamburg|19|18
Spain|Madrid|10|9
Spain|Barcelona|10|9

Map((Country,city) -> (min,max), (Spain,Madrid) -> (10,9), (Germany,Berlin) -> (13,6), (Germany,Hamburg) -> (19,18), (Germany,Munich) -> (19,6), (Spain,Barcelona) -> (10,9))
[success] Total time: 8 s, completed Feb 18, 2016 10:41:31 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a different CSV library, this is fairly simple with [kantan.csv](https://github.com/nrinaudo/kantan.csv):

```
import kantan.csv.ops._

// Turn your file into an iterator of (String, String, Int, Int)
file.asUnsafeCsvReader[(String, String, Int, Int)](',', true)

// Turn each entry into a (String, String) -> (Int, Int)
  .map(c => (c._1 -> c._2) -> (c._3 -> c._4))

// Fold on the iterator to turn it into the desired map.
  .foldLeft(Map.empty[(String, String), (Int, Int)])(_ + _)
```

Note that I've replaced your separator (any number of spaces) with a `,`, as it makes things more straightforward.